# How to transform unit vectors from one cylindrical coordinate system to another one displaced and tilted with respect to it?

Tags: cylindrical-coordinates

I have one cylindrical coordinate system attached with a laboratory device and another cylindrical coordinate system that is attached with an object in it. The object is symmetric about the z-axis in its own coordinate system, which is **both displaced and tilted** with respect to the laboratory system. How do I express the *unit vectors* in the object coordinate system in terms of unit vectors in the laboratory coordinate system? I can write the coordinate transformation in Cartesian coordinates and then convert the Cartesian coordinates into cylindrical coordinates but do not see how to do that with unit vectors.